# MS Paint bitmap encoded weirdly? Trying to do a subimage search with Cython / PIL

Tags: python, format, python-imaging-library, bitmapimage, bytesio

I am trying to do a subimage search with cython.  The way I'm getting the pixel array is:

```
def imageBytes(image):
    with io.BytesIO() as bytes_io:
        image.save(bytes_io, 'BMP')
        data = bytes_io.getvalue() 
        offset = int.from_bytes(data[10:14], byteorder='little', signed=False)
        data = data[offset:]        # pixels start here
    return data
```

Here is the hex dump of a 2x2 pixel 24-bit .BMP image filled solid red except for lower right corner, which is solid blue.

```
42 4D 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00 28 00 <br>
00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 <br>
00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 <br>
00 00 00 00 00 00/00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 <br>
FF 00 00 FF 00 00
```

0x36 = 54 
So the image data starts at the forward slash above.  Going left-to-right in the pixel space and assuming the addresses go top-to-bottom, left-to-right, the next pixel after `00 00 FF` should be `00 00 FF`, but instead it shows blue, hexwise.  And I can't explain the extra all-zero bytes after that.

So how do I get a python bytes object from a PIL image the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

### It says "padded to a multiple of 4 bytes".